# restore lost commit by a known folder name

Tags: git, commit, restore

I have lost a branch accidentally. I guess it is in reflog list, but it's too difficult to check every one in it. I remember that there was a folder created in that branch with some files in it, so it should be possible to find my branch by finding all the lost commits that affects the folder. So the question is: how can I find these commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should just specify the path in the reflog command. It's important to use '--' before the path if it is absent in working tree

```
git reflog -- path/to/the/affected/folder
```

Comment: Note that this shows the same information as `git log -g path/to/it`.

Answer (score 0):

You can grep the output of `git lstree` to find about the commits in a branch:

```
for ID in `git reflog | cut -d' ' -f1` # filter out the commit ID
do
  # show the tree for each commit and grep for the file there
  git ls-tree -r $ID | grep file/name && echo "File is on $ID"
done
```